# Displaying Largest Value in PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array(s) below that are coming from an API I'm working with that I've drilled down to get too, I need to select the one with the biggest filesize and then display all that information. I'm not really understanding some of the other suggestions I've seen here, so I was wondering if somebody could point me in a direction.

```
Array
(
    [type] => video/mp4
    [height] => 180
    [width] => 320
    [label] => H.264 320px
    [filesize] => 257228869
)
Array
(
    [type] => video/mp4
    [height] => 270
    [width] => 480
    [label] => H.264 480px
    [filesize] => 371518109
)
Array
(
    [type] => video/mp4
    [height] => 406
    [width] => 720
    [label] => H.264 720px
    [filesize] => 494828944
)
Array
(
    [type] => video/mp4
    [height] => 720
    [width] => 1280
    [label] => H.264 1280px
    [filesize] => 1042311723
)
```

Here's my code to show how I've gotten the above

```
//Initiate cURL. 
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json' , $authorization )); // Inject the token into the header
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//Execute the request
$result = curl_exec($ch);
    
$json = json_decode($result, TRUE);
$videoids = $json['media'];

foreach ($videoids as $videoid) {   
    //Initiate cURL.
    $ch = curl_init($url3);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json' , $authorization )); // Inject the token into the header
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //Execute the request
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $json = json_decode($result, TRUE);
    
    $playlists = $json['playlist'];
    
    foreach ($playlists as $playlist) {
        $sources = $playlist['sources'];
            
        foreach ($sources as $source) {
            
            if ($source['type'] == "video/mp4") {       
                echo "<pre>";
                    print_r($source);
                echo "</pre>";
            }
        }
        
        echo "<br>";
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably sort, but for fun;  extract the `filesize` columns, get the `max` and search for it in the original array:

```
$sizes  = array_column($array, 'filesize');
$result = $array[array_search(max($sizes), $sizes)];
```

A sort option:

```
array_multisort(array_column($array, 'filesize'), SORT_DESC, $array);
$result = $array[0];
```

Or omit the `SORT_DESC` to get ascending (if you need that for something) and then:

```
$result = end($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your array and then just take the first one:

```
$array = array(
 array( 
   "filesize" => 1234,
   "title" => "item1"
   ),
   array( 
   "filesize" => 12345,
   "title" => "item2"
   ),
   array( 
   "filesize" => 12346,
   "title" => "item3"
   )
   );
   $bsize=0;
    

uasort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    return ($b['filesize'] - $a['filesize']) ;
});

// biggest is $array[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally like array_reduce.  It's simple and clean...

```
$bigplay = array_reduce($playlists, function($c, $it) {
           if (!$c || $it['filesize'] > $c['filesize'])
               $c = $it;
           return $c; }, []);
```

$bigplay will have the information about the entry with the biggest filesize (or an empty array if there were no playlists).